# Need help on logitech script 2 scripts in 1

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

im a beginner and need a bit help in combining this 2 Logitech Scripts in 1

**this is the first one:**

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- to prevent it from being stuck on
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then

        PressKey("z", "n")
        ReleaseKey("n")
end
    if (event =="MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6) then
        ReleaseKey("z")
        PressAndReleaseKey("n")
    end


end
```

**this is the second one **

```
keys = {"1", "2", "1", "2"}
i = 1
lastPress = 0

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
        if(tonumber(GetDate("%y%m%d%H%M%S")) > lastPress +1 ) then
            i = 1
        end

        PressKey(keys[i])
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 7) then
        ReleaseKey(keys[i])

        i = i + 1

        if(i > table.getn(keys)) then
            i = 1
        end
        
        lastPress = GetDate("%y%m%d%H%M%S")
    end
end
```

i tried it a lot but when i put both in one then just the second is working - please help me :)

I tried to put both into one but it didnt worked out

Comment: What specific issue are you having? The conditions don't overlap. This is not JavaScript.

Comment: I guess 5 imaginary dollarbucks that this is Ruby.

Comment: @DaveNewton There you go, I'll give you 10. My second guess is Lua.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you get 10 dollarbucks for a net of zero dollarbucks. https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments, "The conditions don't overlap", so just concatenate them all:

```lua
local keys = {"1", "2", "1", "2"}
local i = 1
local lastPress = -math.huge

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseKey("z", keys[i])
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
        PressKey("z")
        PressAndReleaseKey("n")
    elseif event =="MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then
        ReleaseKey("z")
        PressAndReleaseKey("n")
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7 then
        if GetRunningTime() > lastPress + 2000 then  -- 2 seconds of inactivity
            i = 1
        end
        PressKey(keys[i])
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 7 then
        ReleaseKey(keys[i])
        i = i % #keys + 1
        lastPress = GetRunningTime()
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this fast helpful answer. Its now working but one question i still have. If i want modify the keys to "ö" and "-" or that it is just using the number "1" or "2" of number pad how does it work..

Comment: @e10official - See Appendix A in the documentation (link is given in the tresf's comment) for all available arguments for `PressKey`